# Control Adapters with Mobile Device Browser File

Tags: asp.net, browser, mobile, web-controls

I am using both the [Mobile Device Browser File](http://mdbf.codeplex.com/) and a custom `.browser` file.

In the custom `.browser` file, there are several `ControlAdapter`s registered. I would like to specify in my custom `.browser` file to use different `ControlAdapter`s if the detected device is mobile (provided the Mobile Device Browser File lists it as mobile). How do I do that in my custom `.browser` file? I do not want to modify the Mobile Device Browser File. Thanks.

I am using something like this, but it is not working

```
<browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu"
               adapterType="CSSFriendly.MenuAdapter" />
    </controlAdapters>
</browser>
<browser id="Mobile" parentID="Default">
    <identification>
      <capability name="isMobileDevice" match="true" />
    </identification>
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.Menu"
           adapterType="Controls.Adapters.Mobile.MenuAdapter" />
    </controlAdapters>
</browser>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put my control adapters file into a subdirectory.